# How to do time in each page

Tags: javascript

I am making a quiz that have 20 questions on one page but there is a next navigator for each question.

I want a timer to appear on each question meaning. when you start the quiz the timer begins, click next, timer starts again from 0, go previous, timer continues from where it stopped.

```
   var secondsTotal = 0;

   for(var i=0; i<20; i++) {
       secondsTotal[i] = 0;
   }

   setInterval(function() {
       ++secondsTotal;
       var minutes = Math.floor(secondsTotal / 60);
       var seconds = Math.floor(secondsTotal)  % 60;

       document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =   minutes + ":" + seconds + "mins" +" Taken";
   }, 1000);
```

thats my code.. please help :)

Comment: you have to do something on the server side.

Comment: but i am not using servers

Comment: would have to use either a cookie or localstorage to store each page timer value

Comment: you could even use bookmark hashes but using a cookie or localstorage is far more easier.

Comment: If you're doing everything clientside. Make an array of 'timers' one for each question. use the timer[x] associated with question[x].

Answer (score 0):

You should add somewhere an question identifier for the correspond index in the array `secondsTotal`. Then use that identifier in your `setInterval` function to increase the value `secondsTotal[questionID]`.